# Why does it say my x is not numeric but environment says it is

Tags: r

My code now says x is not numeric, but it worked fine yesterday. I went back into the code and reran it.I tried to turn it numeric but it still is saying it is not. My environment says it is num.
This is the code:

```
is.numeric(pa2)
as.numeric(as.factor(pa2$ï..Approving))
pa2$ï..Approving <- as.numeric(pa2$ï..Approving)
```

I can do boxplots but not histograms. I also can't run any of my cor.test  I'm really not sure what to do. Any help will be welcomed.

Thanks!

Here is some more information:

```
pa2 <- read.csv("C:/Users/thomp/OneDrive/Desktop/FQM/Data Project 2/PA Approval Only Take 2.csv")
summary(pa2)
table(pa2)
sd(pa2$ï..Approving)
pa2_approve = rnorm(pa2$ï..Approving, mean=50.09, sd=11.46188 )
as.numeric(as.factor(pa2$ï..Approving))
pa2$ï..Approving <- as.numeric(pa2$ï..Approving)
hist(pa2)
wti2 <- read.csv("C:/Users/thomp/OneDrive/Desktop/FQM/Data Project 2/WTI Price Only Take 2.csv")
summary(wti2)
table(wti2)
sd(wti2$ï..Price)
wti2_prices2 = rnorm(wti2$ï..Price, mean=43.92, sd=28.1762)
```

My cor.test is:

```
cor.test(wti2, pa2, method = "kendall")
```

Comment: Use `str(pa2)` to check on the type of data that you are working with.

Comment: Hi smithlc, this question is just as unreproducible as your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71903199/how-to-scatterplot-in-rstudio), where I made some [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71903199/how-to-scatterplot-in-rstudio#comment127058466_71903199) on how to fix it. It can be rather difficult to help when we have no data and don't see how you created data; lacking reproducibility, it'll be easy to dismiss the question (it will stagnate) or close it as needing details. I suggest you [edit] both questions. Thanks!

Comment: I have added some information with the code. I'm sorry that my questions were not very good.

Comment: I'm wondering if this part is causing problems `as.numeric(as.factor(pa2$ï..Approving))`. See this for details: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-factor-to-numeric-and-numeric-to-factor-in-r-programming/